# fb sharing to messenger gets "attachment not found " error with php & javscript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, facebook

I am trying to share a page from my site to FB with FB API javascript and php laravel.  The page can be shared to the wall.  But I get an "attachment not found" error when trying to share to private message.

What am I missing?

[image]

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); 
        };
        (function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; 
            js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));
var obj = {
           method: 'share', 
           href: url,
           picture: image,
           name: title,
           caption: desc,
           description: desc
          };
FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Comment: It was most likely a FB problem. It happened to other major sites, e.g. Reuters, as well. I think FB has fixed it. Now it works for me and on Reuters.